# Insert a single pixel into HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas, pixel

I want to insert a pixel with a color, and I use this code:

```
context.fillStyle='RGB('+s[i]+')';
context.fillRect(i,y,1,1)
```

Is there a shorter way to do it? e.g. in a single line of code?
My main goal is to reduce the amount of code.

Comment: You could modify the prototype to build in a fillPixel() function. That's the only shorter way, apart from making a helper function.
Canvas wasn't made to be drawn pixel by pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fillStyle="rgb("+a[m];
fillRect(m,o,1,1);
```

Someone did with that :P

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a shorter way to do it besides the method you used above. You don't *have* to include a `fillStyle` every time so it essentially is only one line of code to fill a pixel.

Like Petteri pointed out there is another way to fill pixels, it involves manipulating the pixel data directly.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/AT9Nm/)**

```
var canvasData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);

//color 100,100 red
canvasData.data[((100*(canvasData.width*4)) + (100*4)) + 0] = 255;
ctx.putImageData(canvasData,0,0);
```

also note with the above method you would need to repeat that line 3 times once for each component of the color. For example to set red, green, blue, and the alpha you would use

```
canvasData.data[((100*(canvasData.width*4)) + (100*4)) + 0] //red
canvasData.data[((100*(canvasData.width*4)) + (100*4)) + 1] //green
canvasData.data[((100*(canvasData.width*4)) + (100*4)) + 2] //blue
canvasData.data[((100*(canvasData.width*4)) + (100*4)) + 3] //alpha
```

granted you could have your data in an array, and just loop through that and color as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the image data of the canvas directly. Here is a good example how to do it: http://beej.us/blog/2010/02/html5s-canvas-part-ii-pixel-manipulation/

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no single line of code way to change a single pixel to one color. Well, there sort-of is.

As Petteri noted, there is a way to change each pixel directly, which will probably accomplish what you want. I assume what you want is to change one pixel to one color, and the next pixel to another color, etc.

For instance here is a function for desaturating a canvas. What it does is takes every pixel and averages the RGB values to be color-neutral (have no saturation). The result is a grayscale image.

```
function grayscale() {
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,can.width, can.height);
    var pixels = imageData.data;
    var numPixels = pixels.length;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);

    for (var i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) {
        var average = (pixels[i*4] + pixels[i*4+1] + pixels[i*4+2]) /3;
        // set red green and blue pixels to the average value
        pixels[i*4] = average;
        pixels[i*4+1] = average;
        pixels[i*4+2] = average;
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
```

As you can see it is iterating over each pixel. It could be easily mofied to have each pixel changed as a one-liner.

Instead of:

```
pixels[i*4] = average;
pixels[i*4+1] = average;
pixels[i*4+2] = average;
```

You'd write:

```
// Take out 3 values starting at i*4 and add the new RGB for that pixel
pixels.splice(i*4,3,REDVALUE,GREENVALUE,BLUEVALUE);
```

Which would accomplish what you'd want. It's not the most efficient way under the sun, but it would accomplish your goal :)